# How can I determine when colliders of two gameobjects touch one another?

Tags: unity, gameobject, collider

I stop gameobjects from colliding with one another by having box colliders around the gameobjects with dimensions bigger than the gameobjects. It works fine, but I want that when the gameobjects collide with one another, they stop moving. I cannot use OnTriggerEnter as I have turned IsTrigger off. Is there a thing which can determine when two gameobjects' collider touch each other?

Answer (score 2):

[`OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) fires when two colliders enter collision (similar to `OnTriggerEnter` but for non-trigger interactions), provided that the moving collider has a Rigidbody attached.

You can also use [Physics.CheckBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckBox.html) / [Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) / [Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc.html) to scan for overlaps in a given prism of space, if you want to manage the physics yourself.